# How to detect data insertion transactions in Bitcoin Blockchain?

Tags: miner-configuration, raw-data

I am wondering how I can detect data insertion transactions from the normal ones in blockchain.com UI?
https://www.blockchain.com/explorer

Thank you

Comment: Why do you assume there is a difference between the two?

Comment: I wanna separate data insertion transactions that are related to the Omni layer from the normal one which is related to the payment system feature of the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

I could find by processing output scripts and detecting op-return.